# Deleting subsequences and inserting strings into a sequence

Tags: r

I have a data file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/waomrba9259yqc3/eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt), which is imported into R by:

```
eya4_lagan_HM_cp <- "E:/blahblah/eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt"

eya4_lagan_HM_cp <- readChar(eya4_lagan_HM_cp, file.info(eya4_lagan_HM_cp)$size)
```

Label the first string with position "1" and the last string as position "311,522" (note the sequence contains in total 311,522 characters). I have two queries which are closely related.

**Query 1)**

Now I have a data file with a list of positions [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym5d72xzk3xubgf/CDS%20coordinates.txt). The positions are read in "pairs", that is, take the first pair 44184 and 44216 as an example. I wish to delete the subsequence from position 44184 (inclusive) to position 44216 (inclusive) from the previous sequence `eya4_lagan_HM_cp` and in its place, insert the character #. In other words, substitute the subsequence from 44184 to 44216 with #. I would like to do this with the rest of the pairs, that is, for 151795 and 151844, I want to delete from position 151795 (inclusive) to 151844 (inclusive) in `eya4_lagan_HM_cp` and replace it with #, and so on.

**Query 2)**

Now I would like to do something slightly different with the data file with the list of positions. Take the first pair as an example again. I would like to insert a # right *before* position 44184, in other words, insert a # between positions 44183 and 44184 in `eya4_lagan_HM_cp` and then I would like to insert a # right *after* position 44216, i.e., insert a # between positions 44216 and 44217. I would like to repeat this procedure for all position pairs. So for the next pair, I would like a # right *before* 151795 and a # right *after* 151844.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
e <- eya4_lagan_HM_cp <- readChar("eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt", file.info("eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt")$size)
pairs <- as.numeric(readLines("CDS coordinates.txt"))
idx1 <- pairs[seq(1, length(pairs), 2)]
idx2 <- pairs[seq(2, length(pairs), 2)]
e.split <- strsplit(e, "")[[1]]

# no1
hashIndices <- unlist(mapply(seq, from=idx1, to=idx2))
e.split[hashIndices] <- "#"
e.new <- paste(e.split, collapse="")

# no2
for (idx in c(idx1, idx2+1))
  e.split <- c(e.split[1:(idx-1)], "#", e.split[idx:length(e.split)])
e.new <- paste(e.split, collapse="")
```

**Edit:**

Another try with reference to the comment: After `e.split <- strsplit(e, "")[[1]]` either

```
# no1
deleteIndices <- unlist(mapply(seq, from=idx1+1, to=idx2))
e.split[idx1] <- "#"
e.new <- paste(e.split[-deleteIndices], collapse="")
```

or

```
# no2
for (idx in c(idx1, idx2+2))
  e.split <- c(e.split[1:(idx-1)], "#", e.split[idx:length(e.split)])
e.new <- paste(e.split, collapse="")
```

Comment: Thanks for that. For `# no1`, I think I didn't phrase my query properly. What I actually wanted was to delete from position 44184 to 44216 (inclusive) and then replace the entire sequence with ONE # and not a # in each position, same with all other pairs. How can I do this? 

For  `# no2`, I think there is a mistake in the code, e.g., for the first position pair the code gives this: f#apkkaakafmfffakkannpaaapkacfaapf#dk whereas the correct placement of # should be: f#apkkaakafmfffakkannpaaapkacfaapfd#k. This goes for the other position pairs too. It seems like # is just a tiny bit off.

Comment: @user3184733 Oops my bad. I make an edit to the post.

Comment: Thanks! `# no1` is fine now. As for `# no2`, although the first position pair is fixed, the second and so forth are still a bit out of place. For example, the code gives a#kkpaaakaaaafkpkfbfakaaofakapkpppfcgaanfpfakaappff#akkp whereas it should be ak#kpaaakaaaafkpkfbfakaaofakapkpppfcgaanfpfakaappffak#kp. In other words, the position 151795 to 151844 needs to be the position of the **original** sequence and not the sequence with the # already inserted, if you know what I mean haha

Comment: Arg! Llooked easy at 1st, but devil's in the detail. Let's break it down. In Theory, you got to add `0:(length(idx1)-1)` to every `idx1` in the loop (for every '#' that has been inserted). The same goes for `idx2`, which additionally needs an `+length(idx1)`. So the loop should look a lil bit dirty sth like `for (idx in c(idx1+(0:(length(idx1)-1)), idx2+length(idx1)+(0:(length(idx2)-1))+2))`. Right? However, I can't test it right now.

Comment: haha yes, I still can't seem to get it, I tried your new loop and the # are still out of position.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the strings that are being replaced are unique, you might try a combination of `substr()` and `gsub()`. (If you only had to do the replacement once, you would only need `substr`.) For example if you loaded your pairs of positions into a 2-column matrix `pp` your query 1 could be

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(pp)) {
      ss <- substr(eya4_lagan_HM_cp,start=pp[i,1],stop=pp[i,2])
      eya4_lagan_HM_cp = gsub(ss,"#",eya4_lagan_HM_cp)
     }
```

and query 2

```
for(i in 1:nrow(pp)) {
  ss <- substr(eya4_lagan_HM_cp,start=pp[i,1],stop=pp[i,2])
  eya4_lagan_HM_cp <- gsub(ss,paste("#",ss,"#",sep=""),eya4_lagan_HM_cp)
}
```

If you can't assume the strings to be replaced will be unique, you could explode out the string `eya4_lagan_HM_cp` into a vector of character strings:

```
vv <-unlist(strsplit(eya4_lagan_HM_cp,split=""))
```

use vector subsetting to remove/insert, e.g., for query 1,

```
new.vv <- c(vv[1:(pp[1,1]-1)],"#")
for(i in 1:(nrow(pp)-1)) {
  new.vv <-c(new.vv,vv[(pp[i,2]+1):(pp[(i+1),1]-1)],"#")
}
new.vv <- c(new.vv,vv[(pp[2,nrow(pp)]+1):length(vv)])
```

and then paste back together as one string

```
eya4_lagan_HM_cp <- paste(new.vv,sep="")
```